# Use Möbius Transformation Normal Form to prove Lambda

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm just completely lost on how to answer this question:

Let $$\frac{Tz-p}{Tz-q}=\lambda \frac{z-p}{z-q}$$ be the normal form of a Möbius transformation with two fixed points.  Prove that $\lambda$ = (Tz, z, p, q), where z is any complex number.

Here's what I know from my class notes:

I know that w=S(z)=$\frac{z-p}{z-q}$ and maps p to 0 and q to $\infty$. To get back to z, I have $S^{-1} $w = $\frac{-qw+p}{-w+1}$.  If I put them together, I have S(T($S^{-1} $w)), which we call Rw.

I know there are two fixed points, p and q, thus I know T(p)=p and T(q)=q. So  S(T(p))=S(p)=0 because in S(z), p goes to 0. R(S(p))=0 so R(0)=0.  That also means S(T(q))=S(q)=$\infty$.  So R(S(q))=$\infty$ and R($\infty$)=$\infty$.

With two fixed points, I can use the form Rw = $\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$.  For one fixed point I have 0=Rw=$\frac{a(0) + b}{c(0) + d}$ where b=0.  And for $\infty$, I have R$\infty$=$\frac{a(\infty)+b}{c(\infty)+d}$ which goes to $\frac{a}{c}$.  So for Rw, I have $\frac{a}{d}\lambda$ and $\lambda$ = $\frac{a}{d}$.

Then I can say that S(Tz)=$\frac{Tz-p}{Tz-q}$, so RSz=$\lambda\frac{z-p}{z-q}$ and that becomes $\frac{Tz-p}{Tz-q} = \lambda\frac{z-p}{z-q}$.

I'm mostly okay with that conceptually--I understand the translations from plane z to w and back again and that we're composing all of these transformations.  What I don't get anymore, is how to relate all of that back to this form: $\lambda$ = (Tz, z, p, q).  And I don't know how I'd *prove* it for "z is any complex number."

The book's hint is: solve the normal form for $\lambda$, and my professor felt this explained the whole question and made the answer obvious, but I'm totally lost.  Some guidance, please??

Comment: Hint: What's the formula for the cross ratio $(z,\, a,\,b,\,c)$?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel!  So if I rearrange it so that $\lambda = \frac{Tz-p}{Tz-q}\cdot\frac{z-q}{z-p}$, I've got the cross-ratio for Tz which equals (Tz, z, p, q).  Thus $\lambda = (Tz, z, p, q)$.  I hope that's enough of a proof!  It seems almost too obvious--which is probably why the prof thought it was so easy...